# PayPal Advanced Card Payments - how to test 3D Secure?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, 3d-secure

We are implementing PayPal Advanced Card payments: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate/

We are in the final stage of implementing 3D Secure. Their 3DS example is incomplete, and we cannot get it working with any of the test cards here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/customize/3d-secure/test/

After spending countless weeks on this, we finally received a reply from PayPal support saying none of those test cards work, it is not possible to test 3DS in the sandbox, and they are in the process of removing the 3DS Test Scenarios documentation I linked to above.

How are we supposed to test 3DS if it doesn't work in the sandbox?  I am hoping I have been misinformed.

Has anyone else managed to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try some other 3DS cards 5232106671708398 , 5356660078288487 , 5356660030805261

Comment: Thank you so much!  Where on earth did you get these card numbers from? They are also returning the `enrollment_status` and `authentication_status` which is exactly what I need. PayPal support told me last night that it is not possible to test 3DS in the sandbox, so I was starting to give up all hope.

Comment: Paypal share this link with me to generate 3D card,https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/creditCardGenerator

Comment: I am stilly trying to test 3D in sandbox but nothing seem to work. MrCarrot did you find  any solution.